# How do I look at [...more] in detail?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

```js
import * as Joi from 'joi';
import 'joi-extract-type';

const schema = {
    aaaaaaa: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    bbbbbb: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    aaaaaaa3: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    aaaaaaa5: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    e: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    f: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    g: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    h: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    i: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    j: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    k: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    n: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
    nnnnnnnnn: Joi.number()
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .allow(null),
};

type exampleType = Joi.extractType<typeof schema>;
```

How do I look at [...more] in detail?

No matter how hard I look, I can't find it.
I want to see of that.
Cause I do a lot of the combinations.
Then there's more than 20 of them.
It's hard to check the type because it's show [...more].

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8o9o.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as image(s)

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: oh sorry... i just want to see [...more] in detail. It's hard to know what the type is because it's more than that.

Comment: The intellisense window is being shortened, since there are just too many entries, this is a vs-code limitation. I am sure there is some option to allow for bigger pop-ups but you will have to researe that on your own. As a quick fix, you can try to use the dot notation to access individual items, like `declare x: exampleType; x.<variable-name>` Where you replace `<variable-name>` with the property you want to look for. Then hover over the variable to see its type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113031/how-to-see-a-fully-expanded-typescript-type-without-n-more-and
Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code's JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense truncates very long types as they are usually not useful (and in fact often introduce more confusion). That's why you see the `... more ...` section

As of VS Code 1.36, there is no way to force the full type to be shown. We have an issue about [interactive diagnostics](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64566) that talks about how types in diagnostics could be expanded dynamically, and the same would also make sense for IntelliSense.

If you think that your specific case could be handled by TypeScript better, please [file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)