# How to view full type definition on hover in VSCode, TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Hovering over a variable or function in VSCode is really helpful by showing its type. However, there are certain use-cases where I would like to see the full type definition of a variable and not just the type alias.

For example: UseState with full type
[image: UseState with full type]
will allow me to see the full type of the variable campaign:

[image: Hover with full def].

But I would really like to extrapolate that type definition and export it so other components can use it too. So when I change things to this:
[image: UseState with type alias and hover]
and hover over the variable it only shows the type alias. How can I get TypeScript or VSCode to emit the full type definition for a type alias? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried right clicking and choosing go to definition?

Comment: Yeah, upon doing that it will sometimes send me to where I am using that variable, and sometimes it will show other places it is used. While useful, I regularly use generics and all type definition is lost after that if the editor will show me that part.

Comment: Did you try command/super + hover?

Comment: Yes. Command hover still only shows the type alias. Super??

Comment: Hm, this has not been solved yet. I am running into the same issue and couldn't find any solution.

Comment: @Simon Currently there isn't a solution other than opening the type information by "command + click"-ing and searching through the typedef info. It's kind of a pain especially when there are nested aliases, but it got me used to digging through source code.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71410112/18244921) has a type that can expand the type into a simpler object type, but it's a little verbose to spam `Expand` everywhere don't you think ;) [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgWzHAlgcwHYGcoF4oDeAsAFBTlQBmA9tQFxRbABOKGaA3KRVAEZzMGGAK4JeEZlxIBfANoBdKaVCQoAUQAeyDABMAPABUAfHigGoEDcAi6cBaVAD8hKLIDSUNlADWEENUozeQZNbX0Dd3kTBwAyQgcGAyUSHQgAYwAbAWg06mxgKDTEZHRsADlqYFC4XQgdBngkVEwsKQB6Np4uigA9R1JSVMzswrymQuLm7ABNCCxq2vr1LRr9RpKWo3bO7q6+oA)

Comment: Related TypeScript feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56010.

Comment: This has been resolved in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70222591/11355954).

Comment: I believe all the answers down there are not satisfying. we need an actual solution to this

Comment: is this a duplicate of [How to see a fully-expanded TypeScript type without "N more" and "..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53113031/11107541) ?

Answer (score 15):

There is a workaround for that useful for debugging. You have to create a type helper that wraps the type you want to expand:

```js
type Prettify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
} & {};
```

**Example:**

```js
type TypeA = {
  name: string;
};

type TypeB = {
  level: number;
};

type TypeC = {
  loading: boolean;
} & (TypeA | TypeB);

// all properties expaned on hover 'obj'
const obj: Prettify<TypeC> = {
  name: 'david',
  level: 2,
  loading: false,
};
```

**Result:**

[image]

Credits to [Matt Pocock](https://www.mattpocock.com/). Source: [@mattpocockuk twit](https://twitter.com/mattpocockuk/status/1653403198885904387)

Also, there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38040) that wants that for IntelliSense.

Comment: This helps with the specific question asked (see the properties behind a type alias), not with [getting the output without truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77000775/1026). If the list of properties is too long, it will still be truncated even with `Prettify<..>`.

Comment: Hey, what's the font you're using?

Comment: @MetehanAltuntekin [Victor Mono](https://rubjo.github.io/victor-mono/)

Answer (score 10):

To get type definitions, you need to set shortcut to **Peek type definition** command. By default, it has no value.

First, you need to go to **Keyboard shortcuts** with `Ctrl+k Ctrl+s` or via UI.

[image]

Then type in the search bar **Peek Type Definition**.
You'll see a corresponding command.

Double click on it and press preferred shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Just as "Go to definition", this only works for manually written-out types.

Comment: @Nickolay, the context of this question specifically pertains to manually written-out types. 

Perhaps a more constructive response would have been more beneficial.

Comment: You're right, of course. My comment was for the benefit of those coming here from a search engine and not reading the question too carefully. In hindsight I should have edited the question instead.

Answer (score 8):

Right click and click `go to Type Definition` should always take you to the typescript type.

[image]

Comment: this is not the case when the type is not explicitly defined somewhere manually

Answer (score 6):

> How can I get TypeScript or VSCode to emit the full type definition for a type alias?

I don't believe this functionality is currently offered by VSCode, however I was able to find a little-known VSCode extension that does this: [ts-type-expand](https://github.com/d-kimuson/ts-type-expand). FWIW, I have no personal connection to this extension or it's creators. I found it recently, but so far it appears to work as advertised and it directly addresses this problem.

[image: Screenshot of ts-type-expand extension]

Comment: Unfortunately the extension you listed seems to be dead. However, I've found this extension that is a complete lifesaver and does exactly what everyone here is looking for:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mxsdev.typescript-explorer&ssr=false#overview

Comment: I'm actively using this extension as we speak...Dunno why you think it's dead @mrbinky3000? The one you found looks interesting too though.

Comment: I installed ts-type-command, restarted vscode, and it did nothing.  I looked at the Github issues for the project and it seems that others have my same issue. One issue was "stopped working completely".  If yours is working, don't upgrade :-)

Comment: Yup: https://github.com/d-kimuson/ts-type-expand/issues/353

Comment: I had a derived union of like 200 keys that were filtered from another object, none of the other answers solved this. This was helpful. Also the issue mention in the comments above was fixed, project is not dead.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think what you want is possible.

The hover function of VSCode is only meant to give you a quick type information about the value, not the full type. In fact, I believe this feature is powered by TypeScript directly so VSCode has no control over what is displayed...

One final note is that the size of what is displayed is limited (probably for performance reason) so even in case where the type definition is displayed, it sometime simply truncate it if it's too long.

Comment: But I think Microsoft can add an option to expand the hover canvas. For example, in jsdocs, you can expand the canvas to see the whole documentation. Especially for the npm library "zod", where types are very long. #zod #type

Answer (score 2):

Go to keyboard shortcuts and add a shortcut to "Add Peek Definition". This works for Typescript, and Golang struct. In my case I am using alt+command+P.

I will highlight the variable and press the keyboard shortcuts, and the type definition shows up like in screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `CMD` while you hover on Mac (probably `CTRL` on windows), you'll see the full type definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the option Peek Definition `Alt + F12` maybe could be helpful in this case.

Comment: "No type definition found for __name__" ... not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Test this :

```
const [campaigns,setCampigns]= useState<{ [K in keyof campaigns]: campaigns[K]}>()
```

Not optimal but you can do so anyway.

Comment: Nope - tried all c/s/a+mouseover on Windows and the only offering is the alias, no insight into the types from which this alias derives.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this vscode extension to put a comment under the type to see its full definition:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-twoslash-queries