# How to copy the inferred type of an untyped function (TypeScript) in Visual Studio Code when its very long

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

(See Screenshot)
[image: Screenshot of function when hovering with mouse]

I have this function with a really long untyped object returned, I want to copy the inferred type of that object because it's way too long to do manually, and then I want to make class/interface of it, example:

```
export class PatientTables {
  emsf: string;
  cadNumber: string;
  // and so on
}
```

is there a way to copy it from somewhere as it seems Visual Studio Code already has it assorted somewhere, as you can see in the picture (48 more), how can I make it show the rest and copy it?
thanks!

Comment: Hold your modifier key (either command or alt on mac, ctrl on windows) and click the name of the function (where you're hovering)

Comment: @C_Ogoo thanks for the quick response, I've tried that and it only shows the function it self and the value that its returning, meaning the object with the key value pairs, not the type of it. for example, { keyname: 'some value' }  and not { keyname :string } which is what im looking for

Comment: ah ok, theres a cool extension that i use called: 'Paste JSON as Code'. You'll be able to copy the ts object (w/ key value pairs) and generate an interface from it. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype

Comment: @C_Ogoo thanks alot again man, that seemed to be working, only it wont translate variable value into type, and is not giving the wanted result (or non at all) isnt there way to expand that "48 more" and copy the whole thing, because it seems Code is doing all the dirty work and it knows all the types, im trying several other extensions and they all end with "..." or "n more" after a few entries just like Code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click the function name, choose "refactor", then "Infer function return type".

Comment: I don't have the "Infer..." option, do you use an extension for this?

Comment: When you hover over the function name, if you can see a inferred type, then you should see that option. Maybe you're in a js or jsx file? Change the file extension to ts or tsx and try again? It will be something like this: https://youtu.be/ZRyrBMmEsvA?t=49

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see this option for me in VS Code 1.63.2  https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_refactoring

Comment: RMC refactor to named function first, then RMC on new function Refactor shows infer return type option.

Comment: Tragically trying this method throws an error for me "Actual command not found, wanted to execute _typescript.didApplyRefactoring /400097"

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to use the `tsc` command line tool. If you can isolate the file so that there are no dependencies, then you can run:

```
tsc filename.ts --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly
```

The resulting `filename.d.ts` file will include the generated type.

Comment: See docs here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declaration

Answer (score 7):

This is a known VSCode issue for which there's a workaround here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35601#issuecomment-921752554. All credits go to github user `LoveriusB` but I will post their solution here for durability:

1. From the directory where you installed VSCode, open the file /resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js and change `ts.defaultMaximumTruncationLength = 160` to something higher like `ts.defaultMaximumTruncationLength = 800`.
2. Restart the TS server in VSCode by pressing F1 and selecting `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`.

The main disadvantage is that you have to repeat this after every VSCode update. This could also be automated with `patch-package` according to this post (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35601#issuecomment-1190985832) but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: if you are using WSL like me, you can find the tsserver.js at  ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.3.20230828/node_modules/typescript/lib

Comment: For Ubuntu (and other distros likely using the vscode debian package), my path is /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js

Answer (score 4):

You can get the type from the following code:

```js
function createPatientTables() {
    return {
        foo: 'hello world',
        bar: 123
    };
}

type PatientTables = ReturnType<typeof createPatientTables>;
```

Comment: This lets me refer to the inferred type, not to copy/view it.

Answer (score 2):

### Use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MariusAlchimavicius.json-to-ts) extension (JSON to TS).

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I think it solves your problem. The extension takes JSON and converts it into TypeScript interfaces.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me; the Visual Code option was not there in the .  So I visited the Typescript playground and *copy-pasted* the Javascript object for which I needed the types.  For ex: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3gWAFA2zAZiEALhgHJ8QSAaTHGAIwEMAnYkxpkzAXyA

[image: This is how it looks:]

Answer (score -1):

RMC (Right mouse Click) refactor to named function first, then RMC on new function Refactor shows infer return type option.

Comment: What's a RMC? Please edit your answer

Comment: Maybe also remove your comment (it's a duplicate)