# What is the name of the capability in VS Code where you can hover over a variable and see where it's defined?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminology

When you hover over a variable in VS Code, e.g., a function name, there's a small pop up that shows where the function is defined and some other quick details. What is the name of this feature?

I'm setting up VS Code on a new computer, and I'm trying to get that feature, but not sure what it's called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in feature is aptly referred to as **hover** or **hovers**.

For example, the docs for the built-in [Go to Definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition) mentions it as:

> If you press `Ctrl` and **hover** over a symbol, a preview of the declaration will appear

It is also mentioned in various language-specific features, such as this one for [HTML Hover](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/html#_hover):

> ### Hover
>
> Move the mouse over HTML tags or embedded styles and JavaScript to get more information on the symbol under the cursor.
>
> [image: HTML Hover]

The relevant built-in settings are grouped by `*.hover.*`, such as:

```json
// Prefer showing hovers above the line, if there's space.
"editor.hover.above": true,

// Controls the delay in milliseconds after which the hover is shown.
"editor.hover.delay": 300,

// Controls whether the hover is shown.
"editor.hover.enabled": true,

...

// Show tag and attribute documentation in hover.
"html.hover.documentation": true,

// Show references to MDN in hover.
"html.hover.references": true,

...
```

The contents however depend on the language of the file (as indicated on the status bar on the lower right of VS Code) and/or the extensions you have installed. For example, you said "*shows where the function is defined*", but for my Python workspaces, they typically just show the function signature and documentation:

[image: sample hover popup for Python]

So you would have to check both the built-in settings and the extension settings if you are looking for specific behavior/contents of the hover popup.

The way for extensions to modify the hover behavior/contents is also referred to as [Show Hovers](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#show-hovers), and so it makes sense for extension-specific settings to refer to it as `hover` as well:

> ### Show Hovers
>
> Hovers show information about the symbol/object that's below the mouse
> cursor. This is usually the type of the symbol and a description.
>
> [image: animation of Show Hovers, taken from the VS Code docs]

Comment: Does Hovers come with "Intellisense?" I've found Intellisense extensions tend to provide this feature

Comment: @24n8 I would say, it's part of that same family of features. Intellisense is the more generic term *not specific to VS Code*, referring to features of an IDE that help you read/write code, like suggestions/autocompletion, highlighting, and info on mouse over. I did not mention it here because VS Code docs on Intellisense does not mention any mouse over or hover behavior: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense.

Comment: Ah I see. After I posted this, I installed an Intellisense extension (for C/C++ in my case) and that seemed to provide the hovers feature. Is the feature pretty flaky for you? I find sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @24n8 It works quite fine for me, though I don't do C/C++ anymore. It is indeed language and extension specific. Just the built-in one isn't that useful, so I think that's why VS Code provides a way for language extension authors to improve the behavior/contents. If you're having issues, you will probably have to report it to the extension authors.