# Vscode typescript is there any method to see type full definition?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

This is simillar with  this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412688/how-to-view-full-type-definition-on-hover-in-vscode-typescript]

But I want to check for undefined type. For example

If i have Json like this

```
const foo = {
  document: {
  participantMappings: [
    {
      excluded: false,
      signingMethod: {type: 'KAKAO', value: 'asdasdasd'},
      verification: {password: {}, mobileIdentification: {}, dCert: {}},
      verification2: {password: {}, mobileIdentification: {}, dCert: {}},
      asdasd3: {password: {}, mobileIdentification: {}, dCert: {}},
      cvvzxczx4: {password: {}, mobileIdentification: {}, dCert: {}},
      hrhrh: 1
    }
  ]
}
}
```

End if i hover at `foo`
[image]

typescript show me definition but it is cut with  `...`

[image]

I want to see this in full type-definition so I can easily copy the types.

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes!!! Thk!! it was duplicated!