# Typescript show union members instead of types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following types:

```
export type AIOId = 'AIO1' | 'AIO2' | 'AIO3' | 'AIO4';

export type AIOXNames = 'AIO1X' | 'AIO2X' | 'AIO3X' | 'AIO4X';

export type AIOAllNames = AIOId | AIOXNames;
```

When I hover `AIOAllNames` it shows the following:

[image: hover]

is there a way to make it display `'AIO1' | 'AIO2' | 'AIO3' | 'AIO4' | AIO1X' | 'AIO2X' | 'AIO3X' | 'AIO4X` rather than `AIOId | AIOXNames`

Comment: Since your union is using only strings, you can use something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvAvMm). For unions using things that aren't strings or numbers sorry, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: That's feature I'd love to see in vscode but I haven't found an option to resolve types recursively when showing those type hints :/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/69553802/995891 is maybe the explanation

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me, although I'm not sure it will work in all cases:

```
export const AIOIds = ['AIO1', 'AIO2', 'AIO3', 'AIO4'] as const;
export type AIOId = typeof AIOIds[number];
export const AIOXNames = ['AIO1X', 'AIO2X', 'AIO3X', 'AIO4X'] as const;
export type AIOXName = typeof AIOXNames[number];
export type AIOAllNames = typeof AIOIds[number] | typeof AIOXNames[number];
```

it unfortunately doesn't lock the union to the subtypes, but that's ok for my case

[image: hover]