# How Do I Get VS Code To Display The JSDoc @typedef Return Value On Hover?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a simple function with JSDoc comments.

```
/**
 * An object containing a person's details.
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {string} name - The person's name.
 * @property {number} age - The person's age.
 */

/**
 * Returns a person's name and age from a string.
 * @param {string} personDetails - The string containing the person's info.
 * @return {Person} An object containing `name` and `age` properties.
 */
const getPersonDetails = (personDetails) => {
  const [name, age] = personDetails.split(',');

  return {
    name: name,
    age: age,
  };
};
```

When I hover over the definition in VS Code I am shown the `typedef` name instead of the expected object with properties.

[image: Hover On Definition - TypeDef Name Shown]

```
const person = getPersonDetails('Bob,23');
console.log(person); // Hover: -> const person: Person
```

This approach does let me at least get a description for each property.

[image: Hover On Definition - Descriptions Shown For Properties]

```
console.log(person.name); // Hover: -> (property) name: string •The person's name.
console.log(person.age); //  Hover: -> (property) age: number •The person's age.
```

If I change the return from `@return {Person}` to `{{name: string, age: number}}` then I am shown the expected return value on hover, but now I do not get the descriptions for each property when referring to them, simply their type.

[image: Hover On Definitions - Return Object Shows Properties But No Descriptions]

```
console.log(person);
/* Hover:
const person: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
*/
console.log(person.name); // Hover: -> (property) name: string
console.log(person.age); //  Hover: -> (property) age: number
```

What I am looking to achieve is to get VS Code to show me both the actual object with properties that would be returned instead of the `typedef` name as well as descriptions for each property when hovering over them.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to view full type definition on hover in VSCode, TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412688/how-to-view-full-type-definition-on-hover-in-vscode-typescript)

Comment: It seems that you might be able to achieve that by adding the shortcut for "Add Peek Definition" or just right click and use "Go to type definition" (or through the appropriate keyboard shortcut)

Comment: @BoianIvanov the goal is to be able to hover and get the information instead of extra steps such as peek definition / right-click -> Go to Type Definition. Basically I want the hover for "person" to be the same as the 3rd GIF in my post while the properties (person.age, person.name) appear as in my 2nd GIF.

Comment: As far as I know and tried myself, apart from adding that shortcut so the new popup would appear or going to the type def, there's nothing else really to do this. I looked around for an extension, but I couldn't find any similar ones. Have a look though and if you find anything similar, please add a comment here :)

Comment: Hopefully some kind of solution pops up! Thanks for pointing out the shortcut.