VSCode Intellisense Unwrap TypeScript Types
Say I have:
type X = Blob | File;

function printX(x: X) {
    console.log(x);
}

with VSCode intellisense, I get the following prompt when I start calling the function:
printX(x: X): void

The problem is that I don't necessarily know what X is, so I have to jump to definition. What I want is to signal to VSCode that I want the type "unwrapped" so that it displays Blob | File for the x parameter when I'm filling it in.
Is this even possible?

Without something like ms/TS#45954 there's no great control for this. TS really wants to show you the exact type you declared when you call the function (I mean, presumably X should be some type name that's actually indicative of what it means). You could play games with generics like this playground link shows but it would be a lot better to just declare it with Blob | File if that's what you want (and then write some checker type to verify that it doesn't diverge from X as shown here).

(see prev comment) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

hey there! are you setting type X = Blob | File; within the same class as you are declaring the function , also can you share a stackblitz

@jcalz - Yes, that answers my question. I appreciate the linked issue and the playground link

TypeScript doesn't give any explicit controls over how types are displayed, and whether they are represented as written (like X) or expanded to their definitions (like Blob | File) or how far to expand them (imagine you had type Y = {x: X}, should it display as Y, or as {x: X}, or as {x: Blob | File}?). There is an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#45954 asking for something better, but for now it's not part of the language.
That means the best you can do is try to take advantage of the heuristics TypeScript uses for displaying types. The most straightforward approach is just to write the desired type yourself:
function printX(x: Blob | File) {
  console.log(x);
}

Of course then it could diverge from X, but you could write some code that would produce an error if that happens:
declare var __xTest: X;
declare var __xTest: Blob | File;
//          ^^^^^^^
// if there is an error here, you need to fix printX

Or, you could try to use generics to prompt TypeScript to evaluate the type more fully when you call printX():
function printX<Y extends X & {}>(x: Y) {
  console.log(x);
}

printX(
//     ^ printX(x: Blob | File): void

Note that I needed to intersect X with the empty object type {} in order for this not to produce just X again. Since neither Blob nor File accept undefined or null, then X & {} is equivalent to X (it's the same as NonNullable<X>, but if you use that utility type then you'll see that, and you don't want it.)
But largely you need to just make do with what TypeScript gives you. If you've created a type alias because it's useful in your code, then ideally you'd give it a useful name so that no matter how it's displayed, there's some hope it will be something meaningful:
type BlobOrFile = Blob | File;
function printX(x: BlobOrFile) {
  console.log(x);
}

printX(
//     ^ printX(x: BlobOrFile): void

Playground link to code

would a problem like this be covered by VS Code's new hover verbosity API once TS integrates with it? I have an answer to that effect in https://stackoverflow.com/q/53113031/11107541, but I don't have the TS expertise to know if that answer would cover this question (and whether dup-closure is appropriate or not).

Hmm, not sure, but I doubt it, since the verbosity API would presumably allow IDE users to selectively make changes, but not necessarily change how it is initially displayed. That is, it would make it easier for someone to hover on X and ask it to be expanded to Blob | File, but not necessarily for it to prevent X from being displayed in the first place. But until it's integrated and testable I can't be sure.
